# syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, script

I was given a script to automate some processes. This script gets executed on a Mac in Terminal. The script is a bash script.

However, Terminal is showing

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

in

```
ManagerDaemon="/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.graphisoft.PortalServerService-v24.0(Manager-2020-07-21).plist"
```

What could be the issue? How can I remove the error?

Comment: Use strong quotes instead of week quotes?  `ManagerDaemon='/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.graphisoft.PortalServerService-v24.0(Manager-2020-07-21).plist'`

Comment: But remember - if you go with what @fd0 said, you can only use them "weekly" so be judicious when using!   That said...parentheses just be avoided in file names altogether.

Comment: ha! and I agree with you about the parentheses. Unfortunately, the software developer decided their filenames would have those.

Comment: Are you related to Clayton?

Comment: nope. nor Sammy, Doug, or Nick - the only other famous ones I'm aware of...

Answer (score 4):

ok, so I think the answer has to do with "curly" quotes or "smart" quotes as opposed to "straight" quotes.

I had been using a text editor to edit the script. However, when I switched to an actual code editor, it noticed several "curly" quotes. I replaced those with straight quotes and all is well.

Comment: Yes, that would do it! Good find.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the broken line. Make sure that the line looks like this in your editor (all on one line):

```
ManagerDaemon="/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.graphisoft.PortalServerServicev24.0(Manager-2020-07-21).plist"
```

Rather than this (with a line break in the middle):

`ManagerDaemon="/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.graphisoft.PortalServerService- v24.0(Manager-2020-07-21).plist"`

Comment: Editor must be warping the view, without inserting the new line characters. It'd be bad for an editor to do the latter